# Eliminar tags html con sed

Tags: linux, bash, sed

Necesito eliminar `tags` en `html` para dejar únicamente el texto en plano. Actualmente con el siguiente `sed` lo he conseguido:

```
sed 's/<[^>]*>//g'
```

Pero...  ¿Cómo podría tambíen eliminar estos casos?

```
[gallery ids="282491,284213"]
```

Comment: Parcialmente relacionado: Tengo la obligación moral de citar esta respuesta al ver que intentas parsear HTML con regex: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/236345

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hasta dónde entiendo, `sed` no permite hacer uso de una coincidencia "No codiciosa", de forma tal de considerar el corchete de cierre más próximo como fin de la coincidencia, sin embargo podrías intentar algo como esto:

```
sed 's/\[[^]]*\]//g' input.txt
```

Hacemos coincidir el corchete de apertura, cualquier otro texto que no sea corchete de cierre y luego si el corchete final

Fuente: [remove string between two character with sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210270/remove-string-between-two-character-with-sed)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes eliminar tanto los tags html como lo que esté dentro de los corchetes con `sed`.

La expresión regular para ambos sería.

```
(<[^>]*>)|(\[[^]]*\])
```

Que combina en dos grupos tanto algún tag html como lo que esté dentro de dos corchetes.

#### Con `sed` sería:

```
sed -r 's/(<[^>]*>)|(\[[^]]*\])//g' archivo
```

Donde `-r` habilita las expresiones regulares extendidas.